# String container for large N

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, data-mining

I am looking for a string container suited for large number of strings (> 10^9).  Strings have variable length.  It must be fast for insertions and lookup and have frugal memory use. Strings are unordered when container is filled. Average string length is about 10 bytes. Lookup done on exact string value. Erasability - optional. N is unknown in advance. For 64bit architecture. Use case - think about associative array for AWK.

`map<string>` have about 20-40 bites overhead per string and each insertion calls one malloc (or two). So it is not fast and not frugal.

Can someone point me to a C/C++ library, a data structure or a paper?

Relavant -- [Comparison of Hash Table Libraries](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-hash-table-libraries/)

**EDIT**
I've removed "big data", bumped N to larger value, clarified requirements.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the requirements? Why isn't a `hash-map` good enough for the task?

Comment: Lookup based on what? Are the strings ordered? You really have to tell us in more detail what operations you plan to do and how you plan to do them.

Comment: @Albert -- unordered_map have about 20 bites overhead per string and each insertion calls one malloc (or two). So it is not fast and not frugal.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- unordered. Lookup based on exact string value.

Comment: You may want to use Boost's `unordered_map` class.

Comment: Are strings ever erased?  Is the number of strings known in advance?  32-bit or 64-bit address space?  (there are reasons for all these questions)

Comment: @TonyDelroy - I've clarified my question.

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky: I believe there is an inherent space-time trade-off to your problem. I don't think you will find a much better container suited to your requirements than a hash table. Maybe a B+ Tree. Maybe a Radix Tree, given that your average string length is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, a pointer on a 64bit machine nearly matches the length of your data. So using multiple pointers per string in your problem (average length less than 10 bytes) would make the size of the data structure dominate the size of your input.

One general way to deal with that is to not use pointers to represent your strings. A specialized representation using a 32bit offset into a large page where all your strings get stored would halve the pointer memory requirements for you, at the cost of needing to do an addition to a pointer to retrieve your string.

**Edit:** Below is a sample (untested) implementation of such a representation (using `struct` for the sake of simplicity, actual implementation would of course only make the user interface public). The representation assumes a hash table insertion, hence leaving room for a `next_`. Note that the offsets are scaled by size of `hash_node` to allow for representation in a 32bit offset.

```
struct hash_node {
    uint32_t next_;
    char * str () { return (const char *)(&next+1); }
    const char * str () const { return (const char *)(&next+1); }
};

struct hash_node_store {
    std::vector<hash_node> page_; /* holds the allocated memory for nodes */
    uint32_t free_;

    hash_node * ptr (uint32_t offset) {
        if (offset == 0) return 0;
        return &page_[offset-1];
    }

    uint32_t allocate (const char *str) {
        hash_node *hn = ptr(free_);
        uint32_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
        uint32_t node_size =
            1 + (len / sizeof(hash_node)) + !!(len % sizeof(hash_node));
        strcpy(hn->str(), str);
        free_ += node_size;
        return 1 + (hn - &page_[0]);
    }
};
```

A hash table would contain a node store, and a hash bucket vector.

```
struct hash_table {
    hash_node_store store_;
    std::vector<uint32_t> table_; /* holds allocated memory for buckets */

    uint32_t hash_func (const char *s) { /* ... */ }

    uint32_t find_at (uint32_t node_offset, const char *str);
    bool insert_at (uint32_t &node_offset, const char *str);

    bool insert (const char *str) {
        uint32_t bucket = hash_func(s) % table_.size();
        return insert_at(table_[bucket], str);
    }

    bool find (const char *str) {
        uint32_t bucket = hash_func(s) % table_.size();
        return find_at(table_[bucket], str);
    }
};
```

Where `find_at` and `insert_at` are just simple functions implemented in the expected way.

```
uint32_t hash_table::find_at (uint32_t node_offset, const char *str) {
    hash_node *hn = store_.ptr(node_offset);
    while (hn) {
        if (strcmp(hn->str(), str) == 0) break;
        node_offset = hn->next_;
        hn = store_.ptr(node_offset);
    }
    return node_offset;
}

bool hash_table::insert_at (uint32_t &node_offset, const char *str) {
    if (! find_at(node_offset, str)) {
        uint32_t new_node = store_.allocate(str);
        store_.ptr(new_node)->next_ = node_offset;
        node_offset = new_node;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no silver bullet, but a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) gives the advantages of a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (fast look up and insert, at least asymptotically)  - with a better space consumption.

However - both are considered not "cache efficient" - which might be significant especially if iteration over the data is required at some point.

Comment: The improvement in space consumption only happens if the strings have common prefixes.

Comment: @user315052: This is not true. Think of a trie/radix tree containing a single word "qwerty". The trie will have a vertex for each character, a radix tree will have a single vertex. Or in other words - distinct suffixes also makes the implementation more efficient

Comment: For a single word. But for 10 different words where none have a common prefix, it turns out to be the same, unless you use a sparse array representation (which will have its own overhead).

Comment: @user315052: I disagree: `aaaaaaaaaa`, `bbbbbbbbb`, `cccccccccc` ,  ... , `jjjjjjjjjj` : will result in 100 vertices (each containing the overhead of a vertex and its pointers) for a trie, and 10 vertices for a radix tree. And, there is no common prefix (except the empty one, of course).

Comment: You're right. I guess the case would be more like each child has a single character common prefix with its sibling.

Comment: `aaa` `aab` `aba` `abb` `baa` `bab` `bba` `bbb` is the simplest case.

Comment: @user315052: It does not *always* save place indeed (no silver bullet) - but for a random/dictionary based collection, the probability of it to happen (the collection will be in the form you described) is slim.

Answer (score 1):

As you're only inserting values, the string data itself can be concatenated as it's inserted - each with a delimiter character such as NUL.  The character offset into that single buffer uniquely identifies the string.  This means that sets of strings that shared a common substring will each be completely redundantly individually specified, but countering that no effort will be spent trying to find or encoding such factoring: that could backfire for highly unrelated string values (e.g. random text).

To find the strings, a hash table could be used.  Given your aim of avoiding frequent dynamic memory allocations, to handle collisions efficiently you'd need to use displacement lists: the idea is that when inserting a string that hashes to an already used bucket, you add an offset (wrapping around the table if necessary) and try that other bucket, continuing until an empty bucket it found.  This means you need a list of displacements to try: you can hand-code a finite list(s) to get you started, or even potentially nesting loops over a "big displacement" list whose values are added to those from a "small displacement" list until an empty bucket is found, e.g. two hand coded lists of 10 displacements yield 100 combinations.  (Alternative hashing algorithms can be used instead of or combined with displacement lists.)  You do need to have a reasonable ratio of total to used buckets though... I'd expect something around 1.2 to work ok typically, with larger values prioritorising speed over space - you could populate your system with sample data and tune to taste.

So, the space requirement is:

```
total_bytes_of_string_data + N delimiters + total_buckets * sizeof(string_offset)
```

Where sizeof(string_offset) probably needs 8 bytes as 10^9 * 10 is already more than 2^32.

For 10^9 strings of ~10 characters and 1.2*10^9 buckets, this is around 10^9 * (10+1) + 1.2*10^9 * 8 bytes = 20.6^10^9 bytes or 19.1 GB.

It's worth noting that 64 bit virtual address space means you can safely allocate much more space for the concatenated string data and hash table than you actually need, and only those pages actually accessed will require virtual memory (initially physical memory, but it could later be swapped to disk through normal virtual memory mechanisms).

Discussion

There's no way to guarantee reduction in the string memory usage without assumptions / insights about repetitions in the string data or character set used.

If all the insertions were followed by a huge number of searches, sorting the string data and using binary searches would be an ideal solution.  But, for quick insertions interspersed with searches the above is reasonable.

You could also have an index based around balanced binary trees, but to avoid memory allocations for each insertion you'd need to group a lot of nodes into one memory page and manually manage the ordering and splitting thereof on a less granular level: painful to implement.  There might be a library doing it already but I haven't heard of one.

You've added "associative arrays in AWK" as an example of what this could be used for.  You could simply embed each mapped-to value immediately after its string key in the concatenated data.

Answer (score 1):

Is a (low) false positive rate acceptable? If so, then [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) would be an option. If you'd be content with a false positive rate of one in a million, or 2^(-20), you'd want to use a buffer size in bits of around 30 times the number of strings you expect, or 3*10^10 bits. That's less than 4GB. You'd also need around 20 independent hash functions.

If you can't accept false positives, you should consider putting a Bloom filter in front of whatever other solution you build, to weed out most negatives really quickly.